# How to handle GZIP-ed ajax responses?

Tags: web-services, nokia, nokia-wrt

Do you have any suggestions on how to handle GZIP-ed ajax responses from a webservice with WRT?My code is working fine on emulator but not on devices (N8,X7).Does smartphone browser supports HTTP- Compression(gzip)?